# Login with google using OAuth and OpenId

Tags: javascript, authentication, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, openid-connect

If i login in through google in my website , it should automatically login in my extension . There should be no need to login in my extension . If would be a great help if anyone can help me out ?
Thank You in  advance!

I had tried logging in my extension but i want to login in my extension through my website